# Populating dropdown list from d/base then using for ajax retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a query relating how to combine a couple of elements:

1. a standard drop down select box whereby users can choose from a list of names sourced from a mysql database table.
2. upon selection from this box- an ajax function which retrieves further data and displays in a html table in a div further down the page. When a new name is selected from the dropdown- the table data refreshes

I can get both elements working individually but not together, i.e. when I write the names individually into the html select bit the javascript/ajax works, but when I implement the PHP to populate the dropdown list automatically the other data doesn't pull in at all.

Some code:

```
<head>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","******","*******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("*******", $con);

$sql="SELECT 
People1.person_id, 
People1.forename,
People1.surname,
People1.team_id
FROM People1
WHERE People1.team_id = 8";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$options="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$id=$row["person_id"]; 
$thing=$row["forename"]; 
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing; 
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
  {
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Player Info</h1>
  <form>
  <SELECT NAME="player_id" "showUser(this.value)">
  <OPTION VALUE="">Choose</OPTION>
  <OPTION VALUE=<?=$options?>></OPTION>
  </SELECT> 
  </form>
<br />

<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In all that above I'm getting the drop down to pretty much populate okay, but selecting names is not bringing anything through from the getuser.php file.

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loop should be the following

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

   $id=$row["person_id"]; 
   $thing=$row["forename"]; 
   $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$thing."</OPTION>"; 
}
```

And you `select` block should be the following

```
<SELECT NAME="player_id" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <OPTION VALUE="">Choose</OPTION>
  <?=$options?>
</SELECT>
```